# PHPUnit_Extenstions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, phpunit, vagrant

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase_WebDriverException : Unable to create session from org.openqa.selenium.remote.NewSessionPayload@1aa12546
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z'
System info: host: 'uplifter', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-48-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_292'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

I am not sure what this error means. Could it be compatibility issue, here's the information:

- Selenium-server-standalone: 3.11.0
- chromium-browser: 65.0.3325.181
- chromedriver: 2.38.552522
- PHP: 5.5.9
- phpunit: 4.8.35
- php-webdriver/webdriver: ^1.4
- phpunit/phpunit-selenium: ^2.0.

I have installed everything in ubuntu using vagrant command line and I am running selenium server in vagrant ssh.

Here is the sample test code:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase;
class SeleniumTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
//      $caps = array(
//          'browserName' => 'chrome',
//          'chromeOptions' => array(
//              'args' => array('--disable-extensions', '--disable-web-security'),
//              'binary' => '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
//          ),
//          'webdriver.chrome.driver' => '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',
//      );
//      $this->setDesiredCapabilities($caps);

        $this->setBrowser('chromium');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('https://jaygym.uplifterinc.com/');

    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        // Navigate to the website
        $this->url('/');

        // Verify that the page title is correct
        $this->assertEquals('Example Domain', $this->title());
    }

    public function testFormSubmission()
    {
        // Navigate to the website
        $this->url('/contact');

        // Fill in the form fields
        $this->byName('name')->value('John Doe');
        $this->byName('email')->value('john.doe@example.com');
        $this->byName('message')->value('This is a test message.');

        // Submit the form
        $this->byName('submit')->click();

        // Verify that the success message is displayed
        $this->assertEquals('Thank you for your message!', $this->byCssSelector('.alert-success')->text());
    }
}
```

I have tried lot of different ways, figured out that facebook/webdriver is newer and cannot be used. I am running selenium server in vagrant ssh before executing the tests.